# Analytic Continuation of Fractional Derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, fractional-calculus, analytic-continuation

I've been doing some work with fractional calculus, and I have been running into a problem. For a given meromorphic function $f: \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$, if a formula of the form $$(D^{\alpha}f)(0)=g(\alpha)$$ has been found where $g$ is as well a meromorphic function has been found, but the proof only works for an open interval $\alpha \in (0,1)$, can a sort of analytic continuation be used to show that this formula holds for all $\alpha$? If not, what conditions would be needed to be able to take such a continuation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the specific case of the [Caputo derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Liouville_integral#Fractional_derivatives) defined by

$$D^\alpha f(x)=\frac1{\Gamma(\lceil\alpha\rceil-\alpha)}\frac{\mathrm d^{\lceil\alpha\rceil}}{\mathrm d^{\lceil\alpha\rceil}x}\int_a^xf(t)(x-t)^{\lceil\alpha\rceil-\alpha-1}~\mathrm dt$$

for non-integer $\alpha>0$, we have the identity

$$D^\alpha f(x)=\frac1{\Gamma(n-\alpha)}\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm d^nx}\int_a^xf(t)(x-t)^{n-\alpha-1}~\mathrm dt$$

for any natural $n>\alpha$. As this last statement holds for all $\alpha$ actually, and is somewhat easily seen to be analytic in $\alpha$ by the same argument used to show it for $\alpha\in(0,1)$, we have an analytic fractional derivative for all $\alpha<n$ for arbitrarily large $n$, and hence analytic everywhere.

The above is usually used to generalize this to complex $\alpha$ by setting $n>\Re(\alpha)$, and the same argument will work there as well.

Comment: What is $a$, the lower bound of the integral? Was that meant to be an $\alpha$?

Comment: @MiloMoses See the linked Wikipedia. The lower bound essentially captures the idea of the constant of integration, so it makes sense to have another parameter that fixes which antiderivatives we take. For natural $\alpha$, this is removed by the differentiation.